# ERROR #11321 API.NODE.EXECUTION "gatsby-source-strapi" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle

Tags: gatsby, strapi

I get this error when trying to communicate from Gatsby to Strapi.

```
 ERROR #11321  API.NODE.EXECUTION

"gatsby-source-strapi" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

  AggregateError: 
  
  - AxiosError.js:89 Function.AxiosError.from
    [my-app]/[gatsby-source-strapi]/[axios]/lib/core/AxiosError.js:89:14
  
  - http.js:591 RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError
    [my-app]/[gatsby-source-strapi]/[axios]/lib/adapters/http.js:591:25
  
  - node:events:511 RedirectableRequest.emit
    node:events:511:28
  
  - index.js:14 ClientRequest.eventHandlers.<computed>
    [ccl-services]/[follow-redirects]/index.js:14:24
  
  - node:events:511 ClientRequest.emit
    node:events:511:28
  
  - node:_http_client:495 Socket.socketErrorListener
    node:_http_client:495:9
  
  - node:events:511 Socket.emit
    node:events:511:28
  
  - destroy:151 emitErrorNT
    node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8
  
  - destroy:116 emitErrorCloseNT
    node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3
  
  - task_queues:82 processTicksAndRejections
    node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21
```

Here are the current versions installed:

- Gatsby version: 5.12.11
- Gatsby CLI version: 5.11.0
- Strapi version: 4.15.4
- NodeJS version: 20.3.1

Plugin installed on gatsby:

- "gatsby-plugin-image": "^3.12.3",
- "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^5.12.3",
- "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^5.12.1",
- "gatsby-source-strapi": "^3.3.1",
- "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^6.12.3",
- "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^5.12.3",
- "react": "^18.2.0",
- "react-dom": "^18.2.0"

I've already filled up some collection types on Strapi, and then I checked Gatsby's GraphQL IDE to see if the Strapi content comes through, but there's none.

I've tried to query on Postman the Strapi's URL and I can see the details coming through.
Anyone who have encountered and successfully solved this? Been trying for weeks now.